# Disable resizing of specific window using Devilspie

Tags: gnome-terminal

I wonder if it is possible to disable resizing of a specific window using Devilspie?

I currectly have a terminal window docked to my desktop background with title bars and frame and everything removed, though i can still resize it and the little resize-button is still there in the bottom right corner.

I know that button can be removed on all windows, what i need is how to remove it on a specific window only, preferably without using compiz.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your Devils Pie configuration file look like for the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

(maximize) command may work. Edit following file.

> gedit ~/.devilspie/yourprofile.ds

and add

> (maximize)

between

> ```
> (begin ...
> ...
> ...
> )
> ```